# Making Quick Jumbar with custom input/array in TableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I have implemented quick jumpbar using the following delegate functions

`sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` and `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {  
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"50",@"100",@"150",@"200",nil];
}
```

but I need to put a dot image in between the numbers for which I have to pass a custom object and then handle the same as it is.

Can any one tell me how to do this, including source code?

Answer (score 0):

The . image is added automatically when there are to many item in the list.